# gradle not able to add project dependency in plugin

Tags: java, gradle

In multi project build I want to add a depedency on specific project via custom plugin. I want to add via plugin equivalent of:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared:model')
}
```

In my gradle plugin I have code like this:

```
Map<String, String> sharedModel = new HashMap<>();
sharedModel.put("path", ":shared:model");
sharedModel.put("configuration", "compile");
target.getDependencies().project(sharedModel);
```

Gradle is running successfully but the dependency is not added to the project. However, if I add above dependency using build.gradle it is working perfectly fine. Gradle info:

```
Gradle 4.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          10.0.1 ("Oracle Corporation" 10.0.1+10)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For adding project dependency from you custom plugin, you need to do this on `apply` method:

```
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
    Map<String, String> sharedModel = new HashMap<>()
    sharedModel.put("path", ":shared:model")
    project.dependencies.add("compile", project.dependencies.project(sharedModel))
}
```